# Screen getting smaller as resolution gets higher

Tags: android, android-layout, screen

I have a weird screen problem. When I load project from my phone, it is seen small and when I click a button it's getting smaller. The project is working well on a 3.7 inch screen.  With 3.7 and higher seen like this:

Screen1:[image]

Screen2:[image]

Screen 3:[image]

Comment: do you have resource images for separate densities like hdpi, mdpi and ldpi?

Comment: Better include your layout xml for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in mainfest.xml file under  tag:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
```

The black space around your activity may be shown cos of density problem but have no idea about why screen getting smaller on changing activities, but try this may be it will help you.

Comment: It is work but i dont understand.Why it is working like that.It is working good 2 days ago.Do you know why?

Comment: dk exactly the reason but, think may be you developed it in previewing 3.7 inch display in xml editor, as the system will have not info regarding to the screen in mainfest.xml, so maybe it takes the default display in which it was developed.